# How do I include external files in PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, html

This code works perfectly, but I can not find how to include an external file.

www.free4g.me/-indexeddb/2.php

Can anyone show how to include a .php file of records?

Comment: Please read [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php include_once 'PATH/TO/YOUR/FILE.php' ?>
```

OR

```
<?php require_once 'PATH/TO/YOUR/FILE.php' ?>
```

include = The file CAN be loaded, otherwise it will throw a notice.

require = The file HAS to be loaded, otherwise it will throw an error.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible include external files, per se.

PHP executes on your server. You'll need to put the `www.free4g.me/-indexeddb/2.php` file on your server, after which you can include it using the explanation provided by Xatenev.